# Use of "mutual" in a positive sense

Tags: grammar

> the feeling is mutual  used for saying that one person dislikes
>   someone as much as that person dislikes them Eleanor couldn't stand
>   the sight of Jenny, and the feeling was mutual.
>   [macmillandictionary.com](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/mutual)

Is it possible to use "the feeling is mutual" in a positive sense?

I like her, and I think the feeling is mutual.

(meaning she likes me either)

Comment: The answer is 'yes'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. It's used all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Whether “the feeling is mutual” is positive depends on what feeling is referred to.  The phrase will have a positive or negative sense depending on what the feeling is.  For example, the phrases *mutual [regard](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/regard#Noun)*, *mutual esteem*, and *mutual liking* all are positive and not uncommon.  [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mutual+regard%2Cmutual+liking%2Cmutual+esteem&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmutual%20regard%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmutual%20liking%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmutual%20esteem%3B%2Cc0) for *mutual regard,mutual liking,mutual esteem* shows the three phrases in wide use since the 1700's.